# Django storages or avatar sets https on my urls so I get certificate errors

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have set my server up with django-storages and django-avatar. When I go to view my site, none of my css or images loads. When I inspect the url i see it is a https and that is causing a certificate error. If I remove the s to make it a normal http then it works fine. What setting have I messed up that is causing the issue?

```
Django 1.4.5
django-storages
django-avatar


import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/'

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://static.XXXX.com.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + 'static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://static.XXXX.com.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + 'static/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static.XXXX.com'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False

#AVATAR
AVATAR_DEFAULT_SIZE = 80
AVATAR_THUMB_FORMAT = "PNG"
AVATAR_THUMB_QUALITY = 90
AVATAR_HASH_FILENAMES = False
AVATAR_HASH_USERDIRNAMES = False
AVATAR_GRAVATAR_BACKUP = False
AVATAR_DEFAULT_URL = MEDIA_URL + 'avatars/default.png'
```

I have used storages (on the same shared server) before with no issue so it leads me to believe that it is avatar that is the issue. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
linked files that are using {{ MEDIA_URL }} on the front end are fine
Images that were uploaded using the avatar are not showing due to the https
admin styles and images are not showing due to https

If it helps the images that are not showing are in a section that requires users to be logged in?

...I am just checking other images now

EDIT 2:

Other images (log & bg image) are ok , but are loaded via a css file on s3

Comment: Try adding this in settings.py
`HTTPS_SUPPORT = False`

Comment: Tried it and nothing has changed my urls still look like this: href="https://static.XXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/css/base.css"

Comment: Are you overriding your settings somewhere? Clearly, this has nothing to do with avatar.

Comment: not that I am aware of. I also have social-auth but I had that before I started to use s3 and avatar so not sure what's over riding it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. The way I did it was by replacing:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

with:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
from S3 import CallingFormat
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT = CallingFormat.SUBDOMAIN
```